# accessing file from the same directory with variable in python flask

Tags: python, path

I am trying to access json file within the same directory the python file exits.I am trying to access it this way:

```
client_secrets_file =os.path.join("client_secret.json")
```

But i am getting this error:

```
No such file or directory: 'client_secret.json'
```

How can i solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to specify the entire path for e.g

```
client_secrets_file =os.path.join("C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\webroot\\client_secret.json")
```

rather than just calling the name of it. If you insist, make sure that it is in the path by doing `os.listdir()` and make sure you are working on your current directory by doing `os.getcwd()`.